# Is there a way to have a customized content add page form depending on who has logged in?

Tags: users, nodes, blocks

I have a website that operates through administrators. Obviously I have the ability to create content pages through drupal's dashboard, but is there a drupal included way (or module perhaps) that will allow me to limit what another logged in person could see? I know I can change permissions to what is accessible by different groups (i.e. users, partial admins, administrators, etc.). I want to be able to actually change what someone who isn't an admin will see. They shouldn't be able to see the drupal dashboard, for example, or certain sections of the "add/blocks" forms/create new content form.

If there is no option that comes defaul with drupal, firstly that is a huge undersight on drupals part, but is there another way to create this effect? One way I thought was to find drupal's core files that add the page (i.e. "node/add") and hardcode php permissions that check who the logged in user is. If they are admins, allow full priveleges, but if they are another group, then disable certain features of the page.

If this is the case, where can I find the files I'll need to edit? I'm having trouble doing so. It would be the actual form creation page that I'm looking for.

Thank you for any ideas and your time.

Comment: The default permissions are quite broad - the dashboard is an easy one, that has its own permission that you can set per role. Permissions for blocks are for the whole admin section, not per block (I think that's what you probably mean by "section"?). You can get that behaviour with https://www.drupal.org/project/block_access, for example.

Answer (score 1):

see this path on your drupal installation :

admin/people/permissions where admin had power to set accessbility of menus,content etc